# jQuery 1.10.2 and ie9 - works only if developer tools is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

I made a website http://ildesignstudio.ru/promo/
It works fine in almost all browsers, but in IE9 it behaves strangely.
jQuery script doesn't work (there's a slider at the top that doens't work, and a carousel in the middle of the page). BUT! As soon as I open the Developer Tools (F12) and refresh the page - it works fine.

All the <script> tags are placed right before </body> and jQuery is loaded from the website folder (not CDN).

Does anybody know why could it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please remove `console.log` form script.js

Answer (score 1):

try adding

```
<script>
if (!window.console) console = {log: function() {}};
</script>
```

so all subsequent console.log will work

Answer (score 1):

or you can add

```
if(!window.console) {
    window.console = {
        log : function(str) {
           alert(str);
        }
    };
}
```